# How do I upload a secondary python file to google cloud platform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I am using the google cloud platform app engine to have a main python file serve up a website using flask and a route in that file that will call a python function that is kept in a secondary python file. Whenever I try to call the function via the website I get a module error. Is there any way for me to upload this file alongside main.py so that I can call functions in it without just copying the file to main.py. Also I checked in each bucket and could not see any of my files in any of them but is there a bucket I should upload it to.

Comment: Can you include some example code and the traceback of the error you're getting? It would be helpful to understand your directory structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are calling from the main.py file in an App Engine application to a function developed by you in a secondary file. If you want that, is as simple as adding the file in the same folder of your main.py and then you have to deploy your application. Then, all the files of the folder will be uploaded to your App Engine application.